# Package path only shown condensed - how to create a file in a subpath?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, package

In Android Studio, when creating a package structure `a.b.c`, how can one create a file in `a.b` as the structure is only shown like this:

[image]

(in other words: no right click possible on `a.b` as it's now shown by oneself)